# Python Logging: Overwriting instead of Appending when using filemode "w"

Tags: python, logging

I have a Python script that runs every 60 seconds.

Within this script, I have a method that prints a message, as well as appending it to `1882.log`:

```
import praw
import os
import logging
from time import gmtime, strftime

logging.basicConfig(filename="1882.log", filemode="w", level=logging.INFO)

def log_it(s):
    o = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime()) + " GMT > " + s
    logging.info(o)
    print(o)
```

It is called within other methods like so:

```
log_it("Message here!")
# "2019-08-28 17:31:31 GMT > Message Here!"
```

I am trying to append each message to the existing history, however **each time the script runs, the log file `1882.log` is somehow overwritten**, meaning that the log history is only the messages output in the *last run*, and not all runs.

I understood that the `filemode="w"` will open the file for appending, and not overwriting, so I'm confused as to why the file is being overwritten completely each time I run this script.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You understand incorrectly. The `'w'` mode will open for writing and *truncate*. This is clearly documented: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Python file open modes", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mode `filemode="a"` for appending. According to the docs for [`logging.basicConfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) that should also be the default:

> *filemode* - If *filename* is specified, open the file in this [mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filemodes). Defaults to `'a'`.

You can see an overview of all available filemodes at that link to the docs:

> ...
>
> `'w'` - open for writing, truncating the file first
>
> ...
>
> `'a'` - open for writing, appending to the end of the file if it exists
>
> ...

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filemodes

Answer (score 1):

Change the `filemode` from `w` (write) to `a`. This prevents clobbering (overwriting) of files. Once you fix that, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Better even than using `a` try using `a+` for your filemode.

The `a` enables you to append to a file and the `+` will create the file if it doesn't already exist.