# with open(file, 'w+') rewrites file doens't append

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a bot where when someone says !redeem  the withdrawn key get saved to a .txt

but whenever it gets saved and somebody else also does !redeem  the previous one gets overwritten and the first person can do the same command again.

The txt is a sort of gaurd from people redeeming the same key twice

Code

```
with open("licensed.txt", 'r+') as file:
   file.write(redeemkey + "\n")
   file.close()
```

Comment: Use `a` or `a+` mode, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). Also, no need to close the file pointer if you use the `with` context manager

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Logging: Overwriting instead of Appending when using filemode "w"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57697509/python-logging-overwriting-instead-of-appending-when-using-filemode-w)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open the file in `a+` access mode if you want to append to the file. `w+` access mode will open the file for reading & writing but will place the pointer at the beginning of file, essentially overwriting the file.

Read more a about the access modes in python file handling [here](https://stackabuse.com/file-handling-in-python/).